# Issue in API Calling

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api-client

See below code:

I used **Javascript** to fetch latitude and longitude for displaying city name using **Google-API**. After successfully get lat and long when i call Google API just after below given API it will not displaying results.

```
if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
            lat=position.coords.latitude;
            long=position.coords.longitude;
            const api=`https://cors.io/?https://api.darksky.net/forecast/API-KEY/${lat},${long}`;
            fetch(api).then(response=>{return response.json()})
            .then(data=> { console.log(data)

            const {temperature}=data.currently
           let celsius=(temperature-32)*(5/9)
            alert(celsius)
            })
        //    

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First as **API-KEY** is missing in your endpoint.it should be replace with key.Hope so It will start working 

`const api=https://cors.io/?https://api.darksky.net/forecast/API-KEY/${lat},${long}`;

Comment: I have removed api key so that it should not go public.

Answer (score 0):

You can call google api in the callback of your first api inside .then block like this:

```
fetch(api1).then(response => response.json()).
  then(data => {
    fetch(api2).then(res2 => res2.json());
  });
```

Hope this helps!!